# Code Analysis increase the build time

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, fxcop, stylecop

Im running my application in VS2015, and i have installed the Nuget packages for code analysis(FxCops and StyleCops). Since my application source is some large code, it takes more than 5 mins to build complete because of code analysis running. This is delay our devlopement process.

Is this any way to stop the code analysis while building in Debug configuration and only enable this in Release configuration? Is this right way to restrict like that?

i have tried the below code in "FxCop.MsBuild.targets" file,

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This didn't help. Could you please let me know the solution for this?

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: Please add related code on your proj file(such as csproj), like this:<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>BasicCorrectnessRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 4):

> This didn't help. Could you please let me know the solution for this?

Please right the project -> properties -> Code Analysis -> Configuration -> select Debug. Then uncheck "Enable Code Analysis on Build".

[image]

Then change Configuration to Release, and check "Enable Code Analysis on Build".

[image]